# Passing a variable from jinja2 template to route in Flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

I have search form on my page, once you input something, i render the same template, but with the search results outputted as a list to the user. The user can click on the results he likes. If the user likes a result (by clicking on the like button), I want do pass this data back to my route, to do some reprocessing of the results. When the user clicks on a like, how can I pass a variable value from my template to my route without refreshing the whole page?

```html
<form class="form-container" method="POST" action="">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
      <input type="text" name="input" id="input" autofocus placeholder="Type your query here!" autocomplete="off" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" style="display:none" />
</form>

{% if output %}
{% for result in output %}
<div>
{{result}}
<span type="button" id={{tag_like_btn}}><i style="color: red" class="fas fa-heart"></i></span>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

```
@irsystem.route('search', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search():
    print ("search")
    form = request.form
    form_submitted = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print ("Form submitted...")
        form_submitted = True
        results = [("Article1", 60), ("Article2", 50), ("Article 3", 40)]
        return render_template('search.html', form=form, form_submitted_status=form_submitted, output=results)
    return render_template('search.html', form=form)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `ajax` to power a dynamic page. First, create the search page, with `ajax` in the `script` section and another snippet of HTML in its own file with templating to display the results:

`search.html`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <input type="text" id="search">
  <button type='button' id='search_button'>Search</button>
  <div id='place_for_results'></div>
  <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#search_button').click(function(){
            var query = $('#search').val();
           $.ajax({
            url: "/search_result",
           type: "get",
           data: {search:query},
           success: function(response) {
            $("#place_for_results").html(response.results);
            },
          error: function(xhr) {
           //Do Something to handle error
          }
         });
        });
     });
  </script>
</html>
```

`results.html`:

```
{%for result in results%}
   <div>
     {{result.val}}
     <span type="button" id={{result.btn}}><i style="color: red" class="fas fa-heart"></i></span>
  </div>
 {%endfor%}
```

Then, in `app.py`, create the route to render `search.html` and another route, `/search_result` to receive the query:

```
from collections import namedtuple
@app.route('/search', methods=['GET'])
def search():
  return flask.render_template('search.html')

@app.route('/search_result')
def search_for():
   query = flask.request.args.get('search')
   result = namedtuple('result', ['val', 'btn'])
   vals = [("Article1", 60), ("Article2", 50), ("Article 3", 40)]
   #below is a very simple search algorithm to filter vals based on user input:
   html = flask.render_template('results.html', results=[result(a, b) for a, b in vals if query.lower() in a.lower()])
   return flask.jsonify({'results':html})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run such arbitrary logic without reloading page, you have to handle sending the AJAX request with JavaScript. Then, your Flask search handler (or ideally separate handler with GET method) should return some lightweight JSON with found articles data. After JavaScript receives the data back from Flask server, it should dynamically create DOM elements and populate it with received data.

To make the code easier to understand I would always render the resulting table with JavaScript - this way you do not have to replicate the code within Flask's template.